# How do I update a class variable from inside of a method for visibility of that variable to other classes in Swift?

Tags: swift, function, variables

```
// some VC
Class FirstClass: UIViewController {

    var tag = -1 // supposed to represent a tag for a UIView inside of FirstClass

        // supposed to change the tag 
        func abc() {

            tag = 5

        }


        // returns the tag
        func getTag() -> Int {

            return tag

       }
    }


// another VC
Class SecondClass: UIViewController {

    FirstClass().abc()
    var a = FirstClass().getTag() // prints -1; I want it to print 5
    let someView = view.viewWithTag(a) as! UIView // nil

}
```

I want to update the 'tag' variable from inside the function. I left out some of the basic functions for simplicity, such as 'viewDidLoad.'
Thanks!

Comment: You are creating and throwing away multiple instances of `FirstClass`.

Comment: You probably need to research how to pass data between view controllers or how to use the delegate pattern. You can't create a new instance of `FirstClass`, you need the original instance or it needs to have passed data to `SecondClass` when that view controller was created.

Comment: This line "var a = FirstClass().getTag()" creates a new instance of FirstClass! Change your code like I showed in the answer, hope this helps. When you want to learn more about the underlying problem: Search for objectorientated programming, understand the difference between a class and an object (also called 'instance' sometimes)

Comment: What is the function `abc()` doing, is the value assigned to `tag` dependent on what the user has been doing or in some other way dynamic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code in SecondClass like this:

```
Class SecondClass: UIViewController {

      let myfirstClass = FirstClass()
      myFirstClass.abc()     // changes the tag in your instance of FirstClass

      var a = myfirstClass.getTag()

      // will print 5 because now you ask the instance, 
      // where the abc-function was called       
}
```

Comment: If both view controllers are designed in Interface Builder the solution will cause unexpected behavior even it prints the expected value.